# String is removing after compilation from variable in SCSS when using for loop or each loop

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am setting up the background image in a different class using for loop in SCSS. But it's not giving the expected output after compilation. I am new in SCSS. Please do help me. Here are what I tried.

```
 $class: avatar;
 $imgSrc: assets/avatars/av;
 $imgType: PNG;
 @for $i from 1 through 10 {
 .#{$class}#{$i} {
   background: url(#{$imgSrc}#{$i}.#{$imgType})  center / contain 
     no-repeat;
  }
 }
```

I also try like this

```
 $class: avatar;
 $imgSrc: assets/avatars/av;
 $imgType: PNG;
 @for $i from 1 through 10 {
 .#{$class}#{$i} {
   background: url('assets/avatars/av#{$i}.PNG')  center / contain 
     no-repeat;
  }
 }
```

In both cases. I am getting output like this:

```
.avatar1 {
  background: url('av1.PNG') center / contain no-repeat;
 }
.avatar2 {
  background: url('av2.PNG') center / contain no-repeat;
}
.
.
```

I am expecting output like this.

```
.avatar1 {
  background: url('assets/avatars/av1.PNG') center / contain no- 
   repeat;
 }
 .avatar2 {
  background: url('assets/avatars/av2.PNG') center / contain no- 
   repeat;
 }
 .
 .
```

Comment: When tested on [an online SCSS editor](https://www.sassmeister.com/), the output of your first code sample matches your expected output. Therefore the problem must be somewhere else in your configuration.

Comment: @Nit I also checked and found the expected result. But in my application, it's not working, I am using Angular 7 with SCSS.

Comment: Sounds like your problem has more to do with how Angular transforms asset URLs when the project builds. You could try using root-relative URLs (i.e. `./assets/avatars/av1.PNG`) or may need to adjust an option in your Angular workspace/project config https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config